# rich:calendar native validation hides/overwrites/?? my bean validation errors

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

My application uses rich:calendars and h:inputText.  If I put input bad data in the UI for the intputText (i.e. non-numeric data) and press "Search" I get the proper error message from the bean.  However, if I put in invalid data in both the inputText (non-numeric) and the rich:calendar(non-date related input such as "foo"), I only get the rich:calendar error messages back.  It is as if the native rich calendar validation messages knocks out the bean validation messages.

How do I get all messages to display?

The xhtml code is as follows:

```
    <html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<f:view>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
    <tr:form id="searchCriteria" defaultCommand="appealSearchManager.search">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="errorMessagesPanel">
            <h:messages id="errorMessages"/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
        <div class="div30">
            <p><h:outputText value="#{messages.ProgramInvoiceId}"/></p>
            <h:inputText id="programInvoiceId" value="#{appealSearchManager.programInvoiceId}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="div30">
        <p><h:outputText value="#{messages.ResponseReleaseDate}"/></p>
        <rich:calendar id="responseReleaseDateBegin"
            enableManualInput="true"  datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
            buttonIcon="/images/calendar_icon.jpg" buttonClass="calendar"
            converterMessage="Invalid Response Release begin date.  Format must be blah, blah, blah."
            value="#{appealSearchManager.responseReleaseDateBegin}">
        </rich:calendar>
        <rich:calendar id="responseReleaseDateEnd"
            enableManualInput="true"  datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
            buttonIcon="/images/calendar_icon.jpg" buttonClass="calendar"
           converterMessage="Invalid Response Release End date.  Format must be blah, blah, blah."
            value="#{appealSearchManager.responseReleaseDateEnd}">
        </rich:calendar>
        </div>

        <div class="searchaction">
            <div>
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a4j:commandLink id="searchButton"
                                         value="#{messages.Search}"
                                         actionListener="#{appealSearchManager.search}"
                                         reRender="errorMessagesPanel, richErrorMessages, errorMessages"
                                         styleClass="searchbtn"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tr:form>
    </div>
</f:view>
</html>
```

and the bean code:

```
    public void search(ActionEvent e) {
    setHasErrors(validateCriteria());
}

private boolean validateCriteria() {
    boolean isValid = true;
    //always check for Program Invoice ID may contain a comma-separated list of ids
    if (getProgramInvoiceId() != null && !getProgramInvoiceId().equals("") && !areValidProgamInvoiceIds(getProgramInvoiceId())) {
        String errorMessage = "Invalid Program Invoice ID.  Must be comma delimited list of numbers.";
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                                                     new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, errorMessage));
        isValid = false;
    }
    //check Dates Response Release Date
    if (!isValidDateRange("Response Release Date", getResponseReleaseDateBegin(), getResponseReleaseDateEnd())) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}

private boolean areValidProgamInvoiceIds(String ids) {
    boolean validIds = true;
    String regexp = "^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*,*)+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    if (!pattern.matcher(ids).matches()) {
        validIds = false;
    }
    return validIds;
}

private boolean isValidDateRange(String dateRange, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    boolean isValidDateAndRange = true;
    Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    futureDate.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
    if ((startDate != null && (endDate == null || endDate.equals(""))) ||
         ((startDate == null || startDate.equals("")) && endDate != null)) {
        //one date is null and the other has a value.  We need both values to do a search.
        String errorMessage = "Invalid " + dateRange + " range.  Missing Date. A date range must contain both start and end dates.";
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, errorMessage));
    } else if (startDate != null && endDate != null) {
        if (isValidDateAndRange) {
            //future start dates are not allowed
            if (startDate.after(futureDate.getTime())) {
                String errorMessage = "Invalid date range.  Start date must be less than today's date.";
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, errorMessage));
                isValidDateAndRange = false;
            }
            //start date greater than the end date is not allowed
            if (endDate.before(startDate)) {
                String errorMessage = "Invalid date range.  End date must be greater than or equal to start date.";
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, errorMessage));
                isValidDateAndRange = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isValidDateAndRange;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not perform validation inside action method. You should perform it using a normal `Validator` which you bind by `<f:validator>` or any of the standard `<f:validateXxx>` tags. The action method is never invoked when validation fails.

For example, to validate the program invoice ID, use `<f:validateRegex>`.

```
<h:inputText id="programInvoiceId" value="#{appealSearchManager.programInvoiceId}" validatorMessage="Invalid Program Invoice ID.  Must be comma delimited list of numbers.">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*,*)+$" />
</h:inputText>
```

Validating the date range is a bit more complex. To the point, you need to put the `Validator` class as `<f:validator>` on one of the components and pass the value of the other component along as an attribute. For an example, see also [Compare two fields that use same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745731/compare-two-fields-that-use-same-class).

By the way, be careful with terminology, you are **not** using ["bean validation"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) at all, but you are just manually validating in the action method.

Comment: I would love to use <f:validateRegex> but the requirements state that I have to gather all errors and display them in one jQuery popup :-(

Comment: BTW - thanks for the clarification of the terminology....being a newbie I'm still grasping for the right words.  I'll try the validating date range as described.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool date validation!  Works like a charm.  Thanks you!!

Comment: Just put `<h:messages>` or `<rich:messages>` in the `<rich:popupPanel>`. It's using jQuery under the covers anyway.