# Issue with <f: validator> and ajax in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to validate two dates in a form before the user do the action. So I got a f:validator inside  a p:calendar working with ajax, the problem is with the f:attribute. I am passing the start date as a parameter and the validator do not receive this date. However if press the action button, the date parameter is there in validation. I am using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745731/compare-two-fields-that-use-same-class) as a guide.
My xhtml is:

```
    <p:column >
                        <p:calendar  id="txtStartDate" binding="#{txtStartDate}"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            value="#{myBean.bean.startDate}">                               
                        </p:calendar>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:calendar id="txtEndDate"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            value="#{myBean.bean.endDate}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validator.dateRangeValidator" />
                            <f:attribute name="fromDate" value="#{txtStartDate.value}" />                                
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" execute="@Form" update=":formHeader:messages" />
                        </p:calendar>
                    </p:column>
```

And Validator:

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null || component.getAttributes().get("fromDate") == null) return;

    Date endDate   = (Date) value; 
    Date startDate = (Date) component.getAttributes().get("fromDate");

    if (!endDate.after(startDate)) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("End date before the start date.");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        addMessageOnSession(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid dates");
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help with that.

Comment: The EL expression `#{myBean.bean.startDate}` is somewhat strange. Is `#{myBean}` specified as `<p:dataTable var="myBean">`?

Comment: No, myBean is my @ManagedBean that contains a property called bean which holds the date attribute.

Comment: So... The calendar inputs in every single row submits to one and same bean property, overriding all submitted values from previous rows until you end up with only the value of the last row? Why this approach? Wouldn't it make more sense to bind their value to the currently iterated row object as you've specified in `<p:dataTable var>`?

Comment: I am not using datatable, I am using a panelgrid with a form, that after submitted will load data in a datable.

Comment: Anyway, a quick solution for me was add a listener="" in ajax  tag, so I am doing the validation at the bean. I dont know if this is the best way to do this, but solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, a quick solution for me was add a listener="" in ajax tag, so I am doing the validation at the bean. I dont know if this is the best way to do this, but solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems that I see here:

```
execute="@Form"
```

The above is incorrect.  If you wish to execute the whole form the correct value here is `@form`.

Once correcting this the `txtStartDate` component should update its binding value and can be set as the attribute for `txtEndDate`.

Comment: I have tried this, but no success. Furthermore I have tried to execute only the txtStartDate and txtEndDate, but without success too.

Comment: Try this: execute="@this" render="yourFormId"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Primefaces**, there is a problem with sending the parameter. They have not support for date.

Your Code:

```
Date startDate = (Date) component.getAttributes().get("fromDate");
```

You have to get date as UIInput and parse.

```
final UIInput startDate = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("fromDate");
final String dateFromString = (String) String.valueOf(startDate.getValue());
final SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
final Date parsedDateTo = parseDate(parserSDF, dateFromString);
```

For update your form use:

```
execute="@this" render="yourFormId"
```

Next hint:

You can change `f:ajax event="dateSelect"` to `f:ajax event="change"` for manual change date input. It also works as date select too.