# how can i get date validation?

Tags: primefaces

I want to have two input date fields startDate and endDate

And the endDate must be after the startDate or error message will be returned

whenever I am trying to enter endDate, I want to get this validation

can you suggest me the best way for this

Comment: next time use search. I think this [ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746141/1692632) should help you

Comment: @Darka:thank you. I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use two primefaces calendar components, where the first one would use ajax www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarAjax.jsf to updated to allowed range of the 2nd component.

the 2nd component could use www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarMinMax.jsf to restrict allowed values.

You can refer to primefaces datarange demo 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarMinMax.jsf